# C#: Howto debug a multiple-component server application?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Question:

I've written a nHibernate API for a C# mailserver.
The mailserver you can find here if you're interested:
http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/MailServer/

And my (buggy) API here:
http://www.lumisoft.ee/Forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=722

The thing is, the mailserver consists of several components:
net dll: all the lowlevel protocol stuff
MailServer exe: the mailserver itself
DB_API dll: the mailserver database plugin-API
Manager: the mailserver configuration manager

Now, my API works fine (meaning it doesn't crash, but not necessarely returning the correct results) in the console application where I tested it.

But when I plug it (nhibernate DB_API dll) into the server and use the Mailserver manager to just adjust the configuration settings somehow, I get null reference exceptions.

Now I need to debug the server by step through to see where exactly the error occurs.
Now, because it consists of multiple components (separate projects), I can't just use step through in visual studio...

How do I debug this?
I assume I need to attach the debugger to the process, but then?

Answer (score 1):

You can set Visual Studio to start debugging multiple Projects at once. Just right-click on the solution in the project browser and bring up the preferences.
There you can find an entry called *Startup Items* or something similar.
I use it all the time when debugging client-server setups, works like a charm.